# Android app UI design

Tags: java, android

I'm just trying to make an android app design similar to the one in the link below.

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id406490694?mt=8

how would I go about making a multiple page application like this?  I've only ever worked on single page applications so any advice you have would be great.

How would I make the buttons at the bottom change the page etc?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app was designed for ios. You should make your app native to the android platform. Otherwise you will be spending a lot of time performing hacks to get the UI to look the same. You may keep some of the design but focus more on how to make this app look great for android.

In terms of switching "screens" you will need to declare each activity in the manifest like so...

```
<activity android:name=".YourClass"  
        android:label="@string/app_or_class_name" />
```

Then when a button or event is triggered you can use the following to load up that screen or activity.

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourClass.class);
startActivity(nextIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use tabActivity for this purpose with tabs at the bottom.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 1):

I have very little android programming experience, But I think I can point you in the right direction.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

specifically look down the page a little at "starting an activity"

It appears that tabActivity is deprecated, so.... I wouldn't use it. The dev guide points to Fragments as an alternative:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

good luck, and I hope someone else answers that knows a little more about it...